# In excel How to split numeric and character values and how to append into different columns using python

Tags: python, excel

{
In excel sheet I have Expected values and actual values columns
I want to split numerical and character values(character values  are units like ps, ns..etc I need to append on one column) and I want to do expected - actual values and add in new column and units in one column
}
My excel and output should be D and e column. We need to do Column B- Column C and units need to add in E

A           B                 C                  D               E
Scenario    Expected         Actual           Deviation          Units
AOP          102ps            100ps              2               ps
COD         113GBd            110GBd             3               GBd
EFG         99Gbps            98Gbps              1             Gbps

my code

import openpyxl
import re
s = '10km'
k=re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', s)
print(k)

Comment: the last deviation is wrong

Comment: Yes typing mistake

Comment: Why are you using Python for such a simple task in Excel itself? Just wondering, is it part of a larger project? Also, 5bps-2Gbps isn't actually 3 when you would use these different units.

Comment: Yes it's part of large project. My project use complete python code so i need do in python it self only. Like this i have multiple excel files i need to do it again and again so that's way am looking for script.  please help me out on this

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two functions to get the text out of your input.

For the real numbers (float):

```
def get_real_number(input_string):
    string_length = len(str(input_string))
    temp_char_list = []
    output_string = ''
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        if not str(input_string[i]).isdigit():
            temp_char_list.append(input_string[i])
    if "." in temp_char_list:
        temp_char_list.remove(".")
    if len(temp_char_list) > 0 and temp_char_list[0] == "-":
        temp_char_list.remove("-")
    if "e" in temp_char_list and "-" in temp_char_list:
        temp_char_list.remove("e")
        temp_char_list.remove("-")
    output_string = input_string
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        if input_string[i] in temp_char_list:
            output_string = output_string.replace(input_string[i], "")
    return float(output_string)
```

For the Unit of Measure:

```
def get_uom(input_string):
    string_length = len(str(input_string))
    output_string = ''
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        if not str(input_string[i]).isdigit():
            output_string = str(output_string) + str(input_string[i])
    output_string = output_string.replace(".", "")
    if "e-" in output_string:
        output_string = output_string.replace("e-", "")
    output_string = output_string.replace("-", "")
    return output_string
```

To make use of the two functions and openpyxl to do what you want, put the two functions in the same py file or import the py file you like to store them in, then use the following code.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment


def main():
    path = 'c:/temp/Pam - Copy.xlsx'
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
    end_range = len(ws['A'])
    cell_value_b_filter = list(("----------------", "Disabled", "Diable", "*", "---", "Null", "Expected"))
    cell_value_c_filter = list(("----------------", "Disabled", "Diasable", "---", "Null", "Actual"))
    for curr_row in range(2, end_range + 1):
        cell_value_a = str(ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=1).value)
        cell_value_b = str(ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=2).value)
        cell_value_c = str(ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=3).value)
        if cell_value_a == "Output File Name":
            continue
        if cell_value_b in cell_value_b_filter or cell_value_c in cell_value_c_filter:
            continue
        if len(cell_value_b) == 0 or len(cell_value_c) == 0:
            continue
        if get_uom(cell_value_b) != get_uom(cell_value_c):
            continue
        cell_value_d = float(get_real_number(cell_value_b)) - float(get_real_number(cell_value_c))
        cell_value_e = get_uom(cell_value_b)
        ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=4).value = cell_value_d
        ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=4).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
        ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=5).value = cell_value_e
    
    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```

If you are not family with python, you can stack the 3 functions all together like this.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment


def get_real_number(input_string):
    string_length = len(str(input_string))
    temp_char_list = []
    output_string = ''
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        if not str(input_string[i]).isdigit():
            temp_char_list.append(input_string[i])
    if "." in temp_char_list:
        temp_char_list.remove(".")
    if len(temp_char_list) > 0 and temp_char_list[0] == "-":
        temp_char_list.remove("-")
    if "e" in temp_char_list and "-" in temp_char_list:
        temp_char_list.remove("e")
        temp_char_list.remove("-")
    output_string = input_string
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        if input_string[i] in temp_char_list:
            output_string = output_string.replace(input_string[i], "")
    return float(output_string)


def get_uom(input_string):
    string_length = len(str(input_string))
    output_string = ''
    for i in range(0, string_length):
        if not str(input_string[i]).isdigit():
            output_string = str(output_string) + str(input_string[i])
    output_string = output_string.replace(".", "")
    if "e-" in output_string:
        output_string = output_string.replace("e-", "")
    output_string = output_string.replace("-", "")
    return output_string


def main():
    path = 'c:/temp/Pam - Copy.xlsx'
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
    end_range = len(ws['A'])
    cell_value_b_filter = list(("----------------", "Disabled", "Diable", "*", "---", "Null", "Expected"))
    cell_value_c_filter = list(("----------------", "Disabled", "Diasable", "---", "Null", "Actual"))
    for curr_row in range(2, end_range + 1):
        cell_value_a = str(ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=1).value)
        cell_value_b = str(ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=2).value)
        cell_value_c = str(ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=3).value)
        if cell_value_a == "Output File Name":
            continue
        if cell_value_b in cell_value_b_filter or cell_value_c in cell_value_c_filter:
            continue
        if len(cell_value_b) == 0 or len(cell_value_c) == 0:
            continue
        if get_uom(cell_value_b) != get_uom(cell_value_c):
            continue
        cell_value_d = float(get_real_number(cell_value_b)) - float(get_real_number(cell_value_c))
        cell_value_e = get_uom(cell_value_b)
        ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=4).value = cell_value_d
        ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=4).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
        ws.cell(row=curr_row, column=5).value = cell_value_e
    
    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: IF i use this functions i will get output in excel format ? And how to parse my excel file here can please help me clearly

Comment: These are just functions to help you separate the cell data so you can then fit them back into where you want the data stored on Excel sheet.
I assume you know how to interact with Excel when you mentioned this is part of a big project and must be only in Python.
You have not provided an Excel sheet structure and there is no way I have any idea where you want the data to be.

Comment: By using this code my data is not adding. As per ur code it is doing into A column  with rows. I want to do deviation between complete Column B - C and append into result into D column and units into E column.

Comment: Lets assume this is excel and i want do operation B and c columns and(Deviation B-C only for values and units to be added in E column) like this i need to do it for multiple columns

Comment: A            B                C                   D(output)                  E
Symbol     Expected          Actual        deviation(Expected- Actual)      units
mean       10ps               9ps               1                            ps
max        5GBd               4GBd             1                            GBd
reslult    5bps               2Gbps             3                            Gbps
delta      11ps               3ps               3                            ps

Comment: Harry am new to excel and python Could you please share complete code properly am not able to fit the code properly 
If you can share the code properly i just run my excel i will see the results.
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please at least give me 1 row of data with the column label and 1 row of expected outcome so I can write it properly?

Comment: Thanks for sharing code. I have ran code by giving my excel path. what ever expected values and actual values are not adding into deviation column and units also not appending. But code is also not thronging error. Can you please check one more time.

Comment: And expected and actual values should be in float values as well. So we need to take care that ex: 52.1243,53.132 like this

Comment: your piece of code is not working get_number and get_text is functions are not working i guess

Comment: Harry In answer 2 i have attached one screen shot. Please access this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9C5r.png my excel looks like this. your code is not appending into D and e. Values expected values subtract actual vales need to store in D and units need to add in E column

Comment: With your data structure and dummy values, I have made some changes to the script.
I altered the get_number() to handle float, and renamed it to get_real_number(). Also changed the get_text() to handle the "." and renamed it to get_uom(). I have created a dummy data in Excel and tested this new one, and it worked without any issue. As I mentioned earlier, it's very important to see your Excel Sheet structure to determine how to proceed.

Comment: Harry can you please share your email id ? So that I can share my excel sheet in stackoverflow am not sure how to share.

Comment: You can send it to Harry.lee@live.com   is it still not working for you?

Comment: i have created this file and it works perfectly. https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ar0IX30aIfIPmmmhhKSfkCFFOUmE?e=Hcyz1I  Do you even have openpyxl installed along your python?

Comment: Harry I have shared my excel via my Gmail to your mail id please check your inbox. I have clearly explained in the mail could you please check. in some cases Expected value - actual value have string and special character so we to take that and append same. But we need to do deviation float values( E- A)  and units we need to append In excel i have explained clearly please the out in excel. If we are getting deviation we need to show color as well. If we are not getting 0 deviation. No need to show color. Please see the excel

Comment: Can you please look into this issue my shared to ur maild I'd please check once.

Comment: @Software, I can only do so much as some of the data are not even valid. I would recommend to perform some clean up on the raw data if possible. Feeding messy data will always carry the potential of breaking the code. Yes, it's possible to create a code to handle messy data but how many exceptions can you foresee and catch realistically?

Comment: @Software I have gone through the sample data file and created this new version of the code, which try to catch incompatible data, such as incomparable values in column b and c, document header, non-numeric data in column b or c. One thing I may no have done right is the scientific notation. I'm not good at that at all.

Comment: Harry to remove messy data I have many excel sheets manual it is not worthfull so that why my team asking script. If it's one excel I can modify give to u. But here many excels are available. One thing Where ever the special characters and string just exclude those cell. Only do that operation float value and append into d column.

Comment: And we need to show colour where ever getting deviation for the cell.

Comment: I'm currently skipping those invalid data rows (as described above). The best way to color the cell is using conditional formatting in Excel, which as long as it's not blank, color the row. Give the current scripts a try and let me know how it works.

Comment: Harry I have tried this logic and added my comments to your mail id. Leave about the coloring the cell I will take care that. But in the mail i have attached excel if u can see for some of the values it is not doing deviation. where ever we have float values need to deviation. it should not skip. That's the requirement and units need to append in units column.

Comment: I added in the a condition to skip any line where the unit of measure are different between Column B and Column C. You are probably referring to those lines. Although the data type for both Column B and Column C are float, I cannot compare them when they have different Unit of Measure.

Comment: Ya correct it is not possible to compare different units to do deviation. Code looks good thank you.